_dbContext.Add query error: Invalid column name
I have two model classes that relate many-to-one to each other:
public class AlertRule: Identity
{
    public long RuleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RuleId))]
    public virtual SepRuleBase Rule { get; set; }

    public long AlertId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AlertId))]
    public virtual Alert Alert { get; set; }//new; it was commented; maybe cause error
}

public abstract class SepRuleBase : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AlertRule> AlertRules { get; set; }

    public override string GetTableName()
    {
        return "SepRule";
    }
}

Here is the Identity model:
public abstract class Identity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    //[JsonIgnore]//temporary. For Json db
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

and the BaseEntity:
public abstract class BaseEntity: Identity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

    public abstract string GetTableName();
}

And the configuration is like this:
public class AlertRuleConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<AlertRule>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AlertRule> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("AlertRule".ConvertDbName())
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID".ConvertDbName())
            .UseOracleIdentityColumn()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.AlertId)
            .HasColumnName("AlertId".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.RuleId)
            .HasColumnName("RuleId".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .HasOne(p => p.Rule)
            .WithMany(p => p.AlertRules)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RuleId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_AlertRule_Rule".ConvertDbName())
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        builder
            .HasOne(p => p.Alert)
            .WithMany(p => p.AlertRules)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.AlertId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_AlertRule".ConvertDbName())//change here
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasIndex(p => p.AlertId).HasName("IX_AlrtRl_AlrtId".ConvertDbName());
        builder.HasIndex(p => p.RuleId).HasName("IX_AlrtRl_RlId".ConvertDbName());
    }
}

public class SepRuleBaseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SepRuleBase>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SepRuleBase> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            //.HasName("ID");

        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID".ConvertDbName())
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn() 
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.Type)
            .HasColumnName("Type".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.Name)
            .HasColumnName("Name".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.Score)
            .HasColumnName("Score".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.Description)
            .HasColumnName("Description".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(x => x.LastUpdate)
            .HasColumnName("LastUpdate".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.LastUpdateBy)
            .HasColumnName("LastUpdateBy".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.IsDeleted)
            .HasColumnName("IsDeleted".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.IsActive)
            .HasColumnName("IsActive".ConvertDbName())
            .IsRequired();

        builder.ToTable("SepRule".ConvertDbName());;
    }
}

I then insert a new row into the AlertRule table:
_dbContext.AlertRules.Add(new AlertRule
{
    AlertId = dbAlert.Id,
    RuleId = long.Parse(rule)
});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

When I use logging for Entity Framework Core, the query that the DbContext tries to run looks like this:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (54ms) [Parameters=[@p0='35', @p1='' (DbType = Int64), @p2='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ALERTRULE] ([ALERTID], [RuleBaseId], [RULEID])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
      SELECT [ID]
      FROM [ALERTRULE]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = scope_identity();

And I get an error:

SqlException: Invalid column name 'RuleBaseId'

But I don't have any RuleBaseId column in my code!
What is wrong with my code?

Please include all text as text not images: including logging output!

I suspect Identity possibly contains this columns and does not have a proper definition.

@DaleK Post edited

@Richard post edited

@Charlieface post edited

Also the Alert type, as well as the IEntityTypeConfiguration for all the types. Looks like you have a duplicate FK defined somewhere. On a side note, good database normalization means you normally don't put an Id column on a many-mnay join table, you just use the two columns AlertId, RuleId as a composite primary key.

@Charlieface The problem is the AlertRule model have a property with RuleBase type with RULE table! but when I change the RuleBase to SepRuleBase and change fk in sql server manually this error happens! I want to change this property type without a migration! How can I do this?
